# ASP.NET MVC: how to add nested property to Modelstate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I'd like to add a property to the **Modelstate** when it's not valid, but I'm not sure how to do that when the property is nested inside another.

Below is what Visual Studio already did for me.

```
<td>
    <span class="editor-field">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TheResource.stateProvince)
    </span><span class="editor-validation-error">
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TheResource.stateProvince)
    </span>
 </td>
```

Now how do I add the property to modelstate on the server-side?

```
if(model.TheResource.countryName == "US")
{
    if(!GetUSAStates().Contains(stateProvince))
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("", 
                                "US state or territory not valid." + 
                                "Please check the spelling. Use, for" + 
                                " instance, Maryland instead of MD");
    }
}
```

So far, I've been using empty string because I didn't know how to add the property. The problem is that it's displaying the error in the summary.

Any idea on how to add a nested property to **Modelstate**?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the fully qualified property name as the first parameter of `.AddModelError`

```
ModelState.AddModelError("TheResource.stateProvince", ""US state or territory not valid ...");
```

Comment: Using `nameof` here doesn't work since it doesn't include the parent object. `IHtmlHelper::NameFor` does what I want, but how does one get access to the html helper in the page model?